# Objectify projection query using keys

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

How do I run a projection query using keys ? I would like to be able to select using a list of  keys and then project on a property.

```
ofy().load().type(Entity.class).filterKey(" in ", keys).project("property1")
```

I got an error message saying: '__key_ _  in ' is not a legal filter condition

```
Also I tried to query by ids which also did not work.

// convert keys to ids
// ...
// ...

ofy().load.type(Entity.class).filter(" id in ", ids).project("property1");
```

I got an error message saying I cannot use id in filter.

I remember being able to do this using the low level datastore api. Please let me know if there is a way using objectify.

Regards,

Sathya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of your extra spaces in `filterKey(" in ", ...)`. It should be `filterKey("in", ...)`.

It never occurred to me that anyone would try something that wacky. And apparently Java `String.split()` is pedantic about splitting for every instance of characters. Thank you for discovering this bug; the fix will be in the next version of Objectify (5.0.4).

In the mean time, stop doing dumb things with whitespace.